# fine grained authorisation solution for istio

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio

**Background**

So, on the journey from monolith(s) mess, to microservices, we've decided to go down the k8s route (already a WIN), on google cloud (likewise), and we're looking for an authentication and authorization solution.

So we're considering using Istio, which again, the RBAC element looks like a WIN, and will allow us to keep authorization outside of the applications, as well as other niceties.

And, cloud IAP. Sweet, we don't need to care about authentication, just grant users (all of which already have g-suite accounts) access via cloud iam.

**Question**

How do we manage & inject auth data for users? IAP lets us grant access to projects, and presents data via JWT (perfect so far), but we can't add custom application permissions.

We would like to be able to use fine-grained permissions for endpoints, and groups/roles to grant these.

After much searching, I can't find any solution, and this seems like a super common requirement.  Have I missed something (am I looking at this wrong?).

Comment: Your question is too broad and it is hard to understand it without any examples. Could you add more specific information about application architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of solutions I can think of:

- Istio (like you mentioned). Which supports:

  - [Transport Authentication](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authentication)
  - [End-user Authentication](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authentication). [Here's an example on how to use it](https://istio.io/help/ops/security/end-user-auth/).
  - For fine-grained authorization, you can use Istio [authorization](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization)
- [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) with [Kubernetes](https://www.consul.io/docs/platform/k8s/index.html) and use [ACLs](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/acl.html) with ACL tokens. The tokens could also be managed by [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/consul/index.html). As of this writing, it doesn't integrate with OpenID or Oauth2 providers. Consul will help you provide that fine-grained authorization with [ACLs](https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/advanced/day-1-operations/acl-guide)

Comment: Thanks Rico. I like the look of istio (for multiple reasons), but, how do I get fine grained authorisation?
Using: G-suite + Google cloud IAP + Google cloud IAM + Istio, we can control access to the application (project) as a whole, but I can't work out how (or where) we would define our own permissions, and how we would inject into the JWT, so that istio can use them to authorise requests.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the original question, yet it is marked as correct.

Comment: Added more to the answer. Basically, you can use Istio authorization or Consul ACLs for finer grain control.  The question is kind of broad, there are several ways that you can architect the system depending on what you are using G-suite, IAM, etc.